# Как присвоить значение i-ому биту памяти на которую указывает void*? си

Tags: c

Есть переменная которая поступает в функцию при помощи void*:

```
void f(void* ptr, int size) {
  ...
}
```

Как я могу присвоить значение i-ого бита (i < size) от *ptr нулю?

Comment: Преобразовать указатель в указатель, скажем, на `char`

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа

```
unsigned char * s = (unsigned char *)ptr;
s = s + size/8;
s |= (1 << (size%8));
```

для установки бита равным 1. Для сброса - использовать `& ~` и так далее...

Comment: это работает только если я знаю тип данных, иначе выдает ошибку 'invalid operands to binary expression ('void *' and 'int')'

Comment: @THND Значит вы код неправильно скопировали. Заметьте, что тут `void *` сначала приводится к `char *`.

Comment: ТС просит i-й, а не size'ый бит

Comment: @Mikhailo Ну замените `size` на `i`...